# WScript.Shell run time error - IwshShell3 failed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have just changed computer and I'm now getting this error "Run of Object IwshShell3 failed". I'm running the macro from MS Access.

The code is:

```
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run strFileName               'execute file
```

Old computer Access version is Office 2013. current version Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus. I've tried referencing Windows Script Host Object Model. Are there any other references that I need?

Comment: The builtin `shell()` can execute a program, if thats all you need simply get rid of that code.

Comment: hi alex. so would that be   shell(strFileName)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Shell

e.g.

```
Public Sub test()
    Shell "notepad", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

You can use longer versions e.g.

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec "cmd /c notepad"
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem cause by the incorrect path of Python. Python should be install in the folder that folder name shouldn't have space.

Comment: This doesn't look relevant: the question has nothing to do with Python.